# Spawn some textures into the screen - libgdx

Tags: position, libgdx, velocity

I have a texture of a soccer ball and I would like to spawn some balls to the air depending on the angle, speed, acceleration, etc.

Now, the setup part is kind of easy. The hard thing for me is to actually implement the launch of the balls into the screen, depending on the above factors. I mean, the physics is kind of difficult for me to understand.

Here is a picture of my project structure:
http://i.gyazo.com/3b07fd4b92fe0c510718b16989193cd1.png

Inside of GameWorld I have an array(Libgdx Array) of Balls and a method called spawnBall which raffles a random x coordinate. The y coordinate is fixed(0) - I want the balls to be launched upwards and then fall downwards.

Now, like I said, the physics thing is hard for me understand. I would really appreaciate if someone will help me out on this !!

Comment: If you don't understand physics use box2d